# Laravel "retrieved" observer removes my objects relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following code:

```
$comments = Comment::with('user.country')
        ->limit(200)
        ->get(['id', 'comment', 'user_id'])
```

I have added a retrieved observer to add some stuff to the original comment.  Something to the extent of this:

```
public function retrieved(Comment $comment)
{
    $comment_country = $comment->user->country->name;
}
```

And the problem is that even if I have already loaded the user and country using `with('user.country')` the comment does not have the user or country objects and hits the database for each of my 200 comments.

I have tested this code without the observer and indeed I get the user and country objects. Any idea on how to force the observer to use the already loaded user and country, because right now it just creates a whole nu object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than 1 query happening here. You need to know the order in which eager loading happens.

The base record set for `Comment` is queried and the result set is filled into models via hydration (causing `retrieved` to be fired). The eager loading is then done by gathering all the needed keys from these models then doing the query to get the children. When this result comes back the children get matched back up to their parents.

If you are following that, the Comment is retrieved and hydrated before the query for the eager load even takes place. So there wouldn't be an expectation of it having the relationships on it as they have not been queried for yet.

The `retrieved` event is fired as soon as the model is hydrated from the query builder.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to get the desired effect? I want to have the countries name inside my comment but I do not want to do 200 queries to get that, I know I can do a join or I can iterate thru the objects and add it but the observer solution seemed more elegant.

Comment: it won't be using the `retrieved` event, that is for sure ... you should expand on what you are actually trying to do and why it needs to be done at that moment in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You were totally right with not doing it inside retrieved. My solution was the following. I have removed the code from the observer that fetched the countries name and did the following:

```
protected $visible = ['id', 'name'];
protected $appends = ['country'];
```

and

```
public function getCountryAttribute()
{
    return $this->user->country->name;
}
```

that along side with worked perfectly

```
$comments = Comment::with('user.country')
    ->limit(200)
    ->get(['id', 'comment', 'user_id'])
```

Note that this solution of mine focuses on the fact that I display this info as a json afterwards.